# Is a function pointer with auto return type allowed as a template argument?

Tags: c++, c++17

I personally like to use a deleter class like this for my `unique_ptr`:

```
template<typename T, void (*Free)(T*)>
struct MyDeleter {
    void operator()(T* ctx) const {
        Free(ctx);
    }
};
```

Because I can easily define different `unique_ptr` types, like this:

```
using my_x_ptr = std::unique_ptr<my_x, MyDeleter<my_x, &my_x_free>>;
```

The only problem is that sometimes the deleter `Free` method may not return `void`. In that case, I can easily resolve the problem by writing another class with a more generic type and check validity of the deleter by SFINAE.

But, I decided to try something like this:

```
template<typename T, auto (*Free)(T*)>
struct MyDeleter {
    void operator()(T* ctx) const {
        Free(ctx);
    }
};
```

and I noticed that this class now matches any return type of deleter `Free` method, which simplifies everything a lot. I have tested this and it works with clang but not gcc, but I'm not sure if this type of template argument is valid, or I'm in NDR world.

Any idea?

**Edit:**

Added a code sample:

```
template<typename T, auto (*Free)(T*)>
struct MyDeleter {
    void operator()(T* ctx) const {
        Free(ctx);
    }
};

void s_free1(S* x) {
    delete x;
}

int s_free2(S* x) {
    delete x;
    return 0;
}

using s_ptr1 = std::unique_ptr<S, MyDeleter<S, &s_free1>>;
using s_ptr2 = std::unique_ptr<S, MyDeleter<S, &s_free2>>;

int main()
{
    s_ptr1  p1(new S{});
    s_ptr2  p2(new S{});
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with gcc

Comment: Can you show what exact thing actually works?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think I was wrong, code only works on clang. Though, my question is still there that if this code should work or not.

Comment: Except for missing `#include<memory>` and `struct S {};` I don't see any reason that shouldn't be well-formed (since C++17).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `auto (*Free)(T*)` isn't a type, so it can't be a template parameter. You could make it one, e.g.

```
template<auto>
struct MyDeleter; // primary template only has non-type parameter

template<typename T, typename R, R (*Free)(T*)>
struct MyDeleter<Free> { // specialisation restricted to function pointer
    void operator()(T* ctx) const {
        Free(ctx);
    }
};

void s_free1(S* x) {
    delete x;
}

int s_free2(S* x) {
    delete x;
    return 0;
}

using s_ptr1 = std::unique_ptr<S, MyDeleter<&s_free1>>; // Don't need to repeat S
using s_ptr2 = std::unique_ptr<S, MyDeleter<&s_free2>>;

int main()
{
    s_ptr1  p1(new S{});
    s_ptr2  p2(new S{});
}
```

Comment: "_Your problem is that auto (*Free)(T*) isn't a type, so it can't be a template parameter._": I don't see any reason that `auto` in this position would be disallowed. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#2 and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec.auto#5 both seem to allow it and the type will simply be deduced via https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg#nontype-1.

Comment: Template parameter can be a non-type. `If the type of a template-parameter contains a placeholder type, the deduced parameter type is determined from the type of the template-argument by placeholder type deduction`  but it seems  gcc devs mis-read the passage same way you do. Template argument  is not a non-type parameter, it's the _actual_ parameter given in specialization ( ISO states that "actual parameter" and "argument" are synonyms)